# Unable to install Chrome due to "dependencies not satisfiable: libxss1"

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, 13.10, dependencies

I have downloaded Chrome from the Chrome download website. When I double click to open it, it opens up the software center, and it says:

```
dependencies not satisfiable: libxss1
```

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 dual booting Windows 8.1 (both 64 bit)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is end-of-life, and the software repositories on the Ubuntu Archive no longer exists, (including those with the security updates).

Trying to use such old version of Ubuntu, and specially connected to the Internet is a serious security hazard for you and for all those that are the Internet.

Please use a recent and supported version of Ubuntu like 20.04, or 21.10!

Answer (score 1):

So as you mentioned you have downloaded the .deb file you can install it from terminal.

Method 1:

```
sudo dpkg -i <your/file/path/to/debfile>.deb
```

If you see dependency issue then try running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then the first command again.

Method 2:

Ubuntu have one more wonderful package which can take care of dependencies automatically named gdebi. To install it

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then simply right click on the file and open it with Gdebi, or run

```
sudo gdebi <filename>.deb
```

Gdebi will take care of dependency problems if possible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: All of those options didn't fix the error

Comment: What's the error you still getting.

Comment: I am doing a fresh reinstall on ext4, but what it says was that it couldn't find gdebi